# IIS 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, php.ini

Good day all,

i am a newbie in windows server environment forgive me for any technical jargon. I created a php web application in an enterprise environment i.e following the 3 tier architecture(db ,application and web server) . The issue i have is that  whenever i upload a large file(100mb) in the web server i get this error :502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server. The same size uploads successfully on application server. But when the file size is small ,no error is returned. I have increased the file size and execution time both in php.ini and iis. I have been battling this error for over 2weeks.

I need your help urgently . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thorough research, i had to increase the proxy server timeout on the web server from 30 secs to 120 secs